# What does Ubuntu use for getting/setting the time?

Tags: command-line, bash, time

There is a way to change Ubuntu's system time in the GUI **Date & Time Settings**, however, as with most tools, I'm assuming that is just a front-end for one of Ubuntu's command-line tools.

What commands does Ubuntu use to get or set the system time? Can these be used in Bash scripts, or are they limited to only be executable by the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [`date` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/date.1.html)

To set the system date to January 2, 1970 10:34:56 am

```
sudo date 010210341970.56
```